# Binary calculator with gmp

Tags: c, calculator, gmp

I am working on creating a binary calculator with infinite precision using the GMP library in C. During the evaluation of a postfix expression, I encountered the error "assignment to expression with array type" when trying to assign the result to a variable.

I am confused about why the result (`ans`) is being treated as an array and how to correctly assign the value of the postfix expression to `ans`. The `evaluatePostfix` function is expected to return a single value, not an array.

Any insights into why this error is occurring and guidance on properly assigning the result to the variable would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
mpf_t evaluatePostfix(char* postfix) { //postfix func
    Stack operandStack;
    initializeStack(&operandStack);

    int i;
    mpf_t operand, op1, op2, result;
    mpf_init(operand);
    mpf_init(op1);
    mpf_init(op2);
    mpf_init(result);

    for (i = 0; postfix[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char token = postfix[i];

        if (isOperand(token)) {
            mpf_set_str(operand, &postfix[i], 10);
            push(&operandStack, operand);
            while (postfix[i] != ' ') {
                i++;
            }
        } else if (token != ' ') {
            mpf_set_ui(op2, pop(&operandStack));
            mpf_set_ui(op1, pop(&operandStack));

            switch (token) {
                case '+':
                    mpf_add(result, op1, op2);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    mpf_sub(result, op1, op2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    mpf_mul(result, op1, op2);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if (mpf_cmp_d(op2, 0.0) != 0) {
                        mpf_div(result, op1, op2);
                    } else {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Division by zero\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    break;
                case '%':
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Modulo operation not supported for floating-point numbers\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                case '^':
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Exponentiation operation not supported for floating-point numbers\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                default:
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operator\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            push(&operandStack, result);
        }
    }

    mpf_clear(operand);
    mpf_clear(op1);
    mpf_clear(op2);

    // Create a new variable to store the result and copy the value
    mpf_t finalResult;
    mpf_init(finalResult);
    mpf_set(finalResult, result);

    // Clear the original result
    mpf_clear(result);

    return finalResult;
}

int main() {//driver
    while (1) {
        struct Num* linked_list = NULL;
        char temp;

        printf("\nEnter infix expression: ");
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n') {
            append(&linked_list, temp);
        }

        char* infix = linkedListToString(linked_list);

        char* postfix = (char*)malloc(strlen(infix) + 1);

        infixToPostfix(infix, postfix);
        printf("Postfix expression: %s\n", postfix);

        mpf_t ans;
        mpf_init(ans);
        ans = evaluatePostfix(postfix);
        gmp_printf("\nResult: %.2Ff\n", ans);

        free(postfix);
        free(infix);
        freeLinkedList(linked_list);
        printf("\nCtrl + c to exit\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line is getting that error?

Comment: `mpf_t` is a typedef for an array type. How else could `mpf_init(ans)` work to initialize it?

Comment: So you should pass `ans` as an argument to `evaluatePostfix()` and it should update it in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types) on types:

> Internally, GMP data types such as mpz_t are defined as one-element arrays, whose element type is part of the GMP internals (see [Internals](https://gmplib.org/manual/Internals.html)).

So you can't assign them like regular variables. The function should receive `ans` as a parameter which it updates in place.

Use `mpf_set()` to assign to an `mpf_t` value.

```
void evaluatePostfix(char* postfix, mpf_t finalResult) { //postfix func
    Stack operandStack;
    initializeStack(&operandStack);

    int i;
    mpf_t operand, op1, op2, result;
    mpf_init(operand);
    mpf_init(op1);
    mpf_init(op2);
    mpf_init(result);

    for (i = 0; postfix[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char token = postfix[i];

        if (isOperand(token)) {
            mpf_set_str(operand, &postfix[i], 10);
            push(&operandStack, operand);
            while (postfix[i] != ' ') {
                i++;
            }
        } else if (token != ' ') {
            mpf_set_ui(op2, pop(&operandStack));
            mpf_set_ui(op1, pop(&operandStack));

            switch (token) {
                case '+':
                    mpf_add(result, op1, op2);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    mpf_sub(result, op1, op2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    mpf_mul(result, op1, op2);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if (mpf_cmp_d(op2, 0.0) != 0) {
                        mpf_div(result, op1, op2);
                    } else {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Division by zero\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    break;
                case '%':
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Modulo operation not supported for floating-point numbers\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                case '^':
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Exponentiation operation not supported for floating-point numbers\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                default:
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operator\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            push(&operandStack, result);
        }
    }

    mpf_clear(operand);
    mpf_clear(op1);
    mpf_clear(op2);

    mpf_set(finalResult, result);

    // Clear the original result
    mpf_clear(result);

    return finalResult;
}

int main() {//driver
    while (1) {
        struct Num* linked_list = NULL;
        char temp;

        printf("\nEnter infix expression: ");
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n') {
            append(&linked_list, temp);
        }

        char* infix = linkedListToString(linked_list);

        char* postfix = (char*)malloc(strlen(infix) + 1);

        infixToPostfix(infix, postfix);
        printf("Postfix expression: %s\n", postfix);

        mpf_t ans;
        mpf_init(ans);
        evaluatePostfix(postfix, ans);
        gmp_printf("\nResult: %.2Ff\n", ans);

        free(postfix);
        free(infix);
        freeLinkedList(linked_list);
        printf("\nCtrl + c to exit\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a similar error in the push function. ``` void push(Stack* stack, char data) {
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;//error
    newNode->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = newNode;
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `data` in `struct Node`?

Comment: typedef struct Node {
    mpf_t data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node; I've used     mpf_set_ui(newNode->data, data); It's throwing seg fault

Comment: Why are you passing `data` as a `char`? It should be `mpf_t data`. Then use `mpf_set(newNode->data, data)`.

Comment: I've encountered a few more problems. When I'm converting from infix to postfix the token is a char but the push function is supposed to take mpf_t as an input. Should I post the entire code for clarity?

Comment: No, please don't. We're not going to debug your entire program like this. You need to figure out how to convert your inputs to `mpf_t` objects before trying to perform calculations on them.

Comment: Barmar, "one-element arrays" --> the sneaky way to achieve pass-by-reference in C with `mpf_...(x);` calls and prevent uncontrolled assignments.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right. It's the opposite of using `struct { int[N] val;}` as a way of passing arrays by value.